# How to display the soft keyboard only on the click event of edittext in android?

Tags: android

My android `Activity` has an `EditText`. Whenever the screen loads the soft keyboard automatically pops up. This obscures the visibility of my screen. I want to display the soft keyboard only on the click event of that `EditText`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In my code I got something like this:

```
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
 imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(password.getWindowToken(), 0);
 imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(username.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

where password and username are TextEdit views.
And to show:

```
imm.showSoftInputFromWindow(username.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: I tried this but still the soft keyboard is popping up on the load event of activity.

Comment: maybe turn off the forced focus on editText and add this to activity in manifest: android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"

Answer (score 0):

Try with this..

```
EditText yourEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

To Close u can use

```
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
 imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

This is how to show and/or how to close it.

So when you start the activity, use first the close code.